# Feedback on a CPP member to C callback wrapper

Tags: c++, c, callback, member

I've been wrapping my head around using a C library with callbacks in C++. For example I have the following method:

`int button(int iconid, const char *label, UIhandler handler);`

which I can use as:

`button(ICON_COLOR, "Some text", callback);`

I now want to use a C++ member but I can't pass its pointer as is. Therefore I have the following wrapper code based on findings on SO and reading other implementations:

```
template <typename T>
struct Callback;

template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
struct Callback<Ret(Params...)> {
    template <typename... Args>
    static Ret callback(Args... args) { return func(args...); }
    static std::function<Ret(Params...)> func;
};

// Initialize the static member.
template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
std::function<Ret(Params...)> Callback<Ret(Params...)>::func;

template <class InstanceClass>
UIhandler ofxBluiCptr(InstanceClass  * instance, void (InstanceClass::*instanceMethod)(int, UIevent))
{
    Callback<void(int, UIevent)>::func = std::bind( instanceMethod, instance, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2 );
    void (*c_func)(int, UIevent) = static_cast<decltype(c_func)>(Callback<void(int, UIevent)>::callback);
    return c_func;
}
```

I can now use the C library as follows:

`button(ICON_COLOR, "Some text", ofxBluiCptr(this, &ofApp::buttonPressed ))`

It works however I can hardly grasp how. Can anybody provide feedback on this and perhaps comment os whether it is safe to  use this way?

Comment: Ok, back to the drawing board. It seems this method only works once. All my callbacks end up being the last registered callback.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to pass member function, and for this you need to "bind" to it `this`.

There are two easy ways to do so. If you can get the `this` pointer, simply create a static wrapper function, that will call the member, usiht this `this` pointer.

In the more likely event that you cannot do so, create a lambda that will capture `this`, and will accept the arguments you want to pass to your CB. use this lambda to as your CB.

```
auto myCB = [this](auto & param1) { this->member(param1);}
```

BTW, whenever you see `bind`, check if you cannot create simpler code using lambdas. In most cases you will.

This has the drawback that it cannot be used there C style function pointers are expected.

To get around this you can wrap each CB with the relevant instance. for example:

```
struct Wrapper{
  static CB_instance* instance;
  static void myCallback(Param1 p1, Param2 p2) {
      instance->callback(p1, p2);
}
```

now, `Wrapper::myCallback` can be used as C function pointer.
If you will templetize it, you will get to code, very similar to the code you started with...

Comment: Thanks for that. I'd better dive a bit more into lambdas as my original method was flawed.

Comment: Isn't this a capturing lambda and isn't it that capturing lambdas cannot be converted to a function pointer? I tried using a lambda like this: `auto myCB = [this](int &param1, UIevent &param2 ) { return this->buttonPressed2(param1, param2);};` but I can't pass it as a callback: `no matching function for call to ‘ofxBlui::button(BNDicon, const char [8], ofApp::setup()::<lambda(int&, UIevent&)>&)’
     blui.column_append(col, blui.button(BND_ICON_HELP, "Ghost 2", myCB ));`